# Need Suggestion to do a task when Android Boots-Up

Tags: android

I have written an activity A, when users press a button, it will do MyConfig.doSomething() where MyConfig is simple class with activity A passed to it.

```
public class A extends PreferenceActivity {
    private MyConfig mMyConfig;

    /* pseudo code, when button clicked, call */        
    mMyConfig.doSomething();
}
```

In mMyConfig, it accesses SharedPreferences for some configuration. Thus, I can do this to pass the activity to mMyConfig for calling getSharedPreferences().

```
mMyConfig = new MyConfig ( this );
```

Here comes my request:

I want to do something that `MyConfig.doSomething()` already does, but except when users click some button to invoke it, I want to invoke it when Android Boots-Up.

I can write another class to extend BroadcastReceiver and then starts activity A by calling `startActivity(A.class)`, and then in A, do some tricks to make `mMyConfig.doSomething()` happen. It works but the Application will be shown on screen when Android Boots-Up.

I want to make `mMyConfig.doSomething()` happen implicitly without letting users be aware of it. I suppose two possible solutions but I don't know how to do it.

Solution A:
Write a class that extends BroadcastReceiver, start a service (instead of activity A) that reads the SharedPreferences of A and create MyConfig object to do `doSomething()`. However, I don't if this can work if activity itself is never launched and how could I do this (read SharedPreferences from a service)?

Solution B:
Write a class that extends BroadcastReceiver, start activity A without showing it, put it to activity stack by calling `startActivity(A.class)` in onReceive. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Activity, which are meant to be visible to the user, you can make your BoardcastReceiver to start a `Service` instead. It is meant to perform tasks in the background without disturbing the user. [The official guide is a nice place to start with.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

**Edited:**

To access the SharedPreference of your application, simply call this line inside your service:

`SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences();`

Comment: I know I can start a Service at BroadcastReceiver, but I'm wondering if this service can access the Activity's SharedPreferences. The Activity A can be launched by users to setup configurations, but in addition to this, I want to doSomething() with the configurations when system boots-up.

Comment: Yes, all components of an application can access the application's shared preferences, accessed via getDefaultSharedPreferences().  There might be a way to get activity-specific preferences, but I forget what it is, and the application-wide preferences are the way to go anyway.

Comment: @minhong yes, a service can also access the SharedPreference because it is in the same package as the activity. SharedPreference is bound to the whole application, not only certain activities. Please see my edited answer to see how you can access it.

Comment: Appreciated. My mistake to misunderstand something on this API. I'll try it!